# jQuery on click event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

if using the following code:

```
$("#element").on('click', function(){
   alert("clicked!");
});

$("#element").on('click', function(){
   alert("clicked!");
});
```

it is well known that the click event will fire twice. because it was bound with the method `on()` and no unbinding with `off()` followed.

Now my question is

why on this [page](http://api.jquery.com/off/) the click event method is registered only once no matter how many times you click the binding button??

```
<script>
function flash() {
  $( "div" ).show().fadeOut( "slow" );
}
$( "#bind" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .on( "click", "#theone", flash )
    .find( "#theone" )
      .text( "Can Click!" );
});
$( "#unbind" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .off( "click", "#theone", flash )
    .find( "#theone" )
      .text( "Does nothing..." );
});
</script>
```

I thought that is because the `on()` method was binding to a named function not anonymous function. but I tested it on jsbin  [here](http://jsbin.com/cimafisu/1/edit)  and it failed ?
can any one give me a hint of what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ed6A3/).
The same code as in jQuery docs but with small modification:

```
function flash() {
    $("div").show().fadeOut("slow");
    alert('hi');
}
```

It shows how `on` works - exactly the same way as you've described. Called by `click` function in the documentation don't show multiple binding. Then `off` turns off all assigned click handlers.

Answer (score 2):

The click method is actually registered and called several times, but each of the several event handlers does the same thing, namely fading out the button. You visually cannot notice the multiple calls, as the multiple "fadings" happen (quasi-)synchronously (are controlled by an internal timer), i.e. jQuery does not wait until the button has completely disappeared before continuing with the program. The second handler is called while the button is still visible.

If there are several identical handlers registered, a single call of `off()` removes them *all* at once. If you add `$("#b").off ('click', doIt)` at the end of your own example, you will see that your button does not do anything anymore.

```
  $("#b").on('click', doIt);

  $("#b").on('click', doIt);

  $("#b").on('click', doIt);

  $("#b").on('click', doIt);

  $("#b").off('click', doIt); // removes all event handlers that are equal (===) to doIt

  // hence now no event handler is registered to #b anymore
```